# LinearLayout ajust with Image size

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

This is my xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/linhaCliente"
    android:clickable="false">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center|left"
                        android:layout_weight="1">


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/telefone"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="(43)123456"
                            android:textSize="20dp"

                            android:textColor="#696969"
                            android:clickable="true"

                            android:phoneNumber="true" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <View
                        android:layout_width="1dp"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:background="#d6d6d6"
                        />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center|right"
                        android:columnCount="2"
                        android:paddingRight="5dp">


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/phone"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
                            android:layout_width="96px"
                            android:layout_height="96px"
                            android:clickable="true" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:gravity="center">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:gravity="left"

                       >



                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/tipoTelefone"
                            android:text="Trabalho "
                            android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
                            android:textSize="15dp"

                            />


                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the result of that is:

[image]

I can't figure out how to set the "TRABALHO" TextView just below of the phone number, like in the people app, it has a vertical divider and an icon, the problem is when I change my icon size it pushes the textview down. the image below shows What I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you want,

Some sidenotes:

1. you were abusing `LinearLayout` (using more than necessary) the more complex the view hierarchy the more slow the interface will be;
2. avoid using px when specifieng a dimension in layouts such as what you were doing in the `ImageView` (using dp's allows for the UI to better scale when used in different screen sizes
3. `android:phoneNumber="true"` is meant to be used in `EditText` and not in `TextView`
4. If your target is API 11 or greater you can use `android:showDividers`instead of using a view for the vertical divider bettween the image and the text

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:orientation="vertical">

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/telefone"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:text="(43)123456"
           android:textColor="#696969"

           android:textSize="20dp"/>

       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/tipoTelefone"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Trabalho "
           android:textColor="#aaaaaa"
           android:textSize="15dp"

           />
   </LinearLayout>

   <View
       android:layout_width="1dp"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:background="#d6d6d6"
       />


   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/phone"
       android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
       android:layout_width="96px"
       android:layout_height="96px"
       android:clickable="true"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
   ```